# is it possible to divide JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript

Like, I've a condition like this:

```
var a="avar", b=3;
var a+b="some value";
// expecting to make, avar3="some value";
```

Is it possible somehow?
Or any alternative way?

Comment: Did you try doing it? What did you find?

Comment: i dont think so you can do that

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Why don't you just `var avar3`?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? You can always use objects as dictionaries and add properties that way. You can also do that with the global object (`window` in the browser). There's generally little reason to do that, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
var a="avar", b=3;
window[a+b]="some value";
```

This will declare a global variable `avar3` with value `"some value"`

Comment: It's important to note that here, `window` refers to the global object. In a browser, it is `window`, but the same might not necessarily carry over to other JavaScript applications (e.g., Node.js).

Comment: Just what I wanted :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
function ns() { return this; }

var a="avar", b=3;
ns()[a+b] = "some value";

alert(avar3);
```

will create variable with the name "avar3" in current namespace.

Answer (score 1):

No Doesn't work like that.

i dont know if this if what you're trying to do but:

var c=a+b;
c="some value";

Answer (score 0):

you can use object properties for something like this

```
 var obj = { a: 'avar', b:'3'};
 obj[obj.a+obj.b]='some value';
 console.log(obj.avar3);  //the output is 'some value'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fGaFJ/